# How to remove blank comments from table?

Tags: mysql, comments

I have table and I have tried to remove comments but it gives me a blank comment still.

[image]

I have used

```
ALTER TABLE `b2b`.`mailsysy` 

COMMENT = '' ;
```

to remove existing comment but it puts blak as comment so what to do if I want to remove all comment put only one comment on it.

**EDIT**

I have tried this also :

[image]

Comment: What did you expect? That is a column in the tables table. You can't remove the record. Only set the comment to null or '' which you did

Comment: Means there is no way to remove that blanks ? Shall I have to create new table and fill out data again ?

Comment: I think you don't know what your select actually returns. replace `table_comment` with `*` and see the complete record.

Comment: It gives me lot's of fields like `table_catalog,table_schema,table_collation, etc. etc.` but what you want to tell me still I don't understand.

Comment: `table_comment` is not a record, it can't be removed. It is a column in `information_schema.tables` - it is always there. This column is filled if given table has a comment, and it is blank if a table has no comment. Even if you create a table without any comment, the column `table_comment` is still there, but it is blank --> see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/946bb3/2 there are two tables, one with a comment, and the other without a comment.

Comment: The record contains all information of a table in your DB. The comment is just one column of that record. You can't remove the record or your table info will be gone completely. You can only set the comment empty.

Comment: @kordirko & juergen d : then what I ll have to do in this situation ? to remove blank detailss because I have used this select query on admin side to fetch comment while displaying table name.

Comment: Shall I replace that fields ? Or do something that will avoid to drop existing table and creating new one ? Any option or idea to do so ?

Comment: Modify your query - add `is not null` condition --> `SELECT table_comment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name ='xxx' AND TABLE_COMMENT IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @kordirko : still it shows 3 records. Same o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to retrieve empty comments, then skip them in your query:

```
SELECT table_comment 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name ='xxx' 
  AND TABLE_COMMENT IS NOT NULL
  AND TABLE_COMMENT <> ''
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8664d/2

Comment: Sir, when I am trying to execute `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='mailsys';` query it gives me 3 times column name, so what to do to get it only once ?

Comment: Sir I have used `select DISTINCT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name= 'mailsys';` now it works but now problem is it gives me the older name of column name that I have updated. i.e. before my column name is message_if then I have changed it to message_id so both display.

Comment: Have done it just added AND ``TABLE_SCHEMA`='b2b'` after that and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The column `TABLE_COMMENT` in `TABLES` and `COLUMN_COMMENT` in `COLUMNS` are part of those tables. They are not separated into any child tables. Due to the reason, though you set *comments* to be empty, the select query returns a row.

The other point you are ignoring is, you are selecting only a column from the `TABLES` table and omitting other columns though have a record satisfying your where condition. If the where condition is not satisfied, the query would have resulted `Empty set (0.00 sec)`. In your case query resulted 3 rows on other data, that have comments set to empty. And hence you see `3 rows in set (0.01 sec)`.

I think you are expecting that if a comment is not defined, query should have not fetched a row from the table. If that was the requirements, please note that there is no such child table `TABLE_COMMENTS` or `COLUMN_COMMENTS`, which if defined correctly might have had a parent-child relation on `TABLES` and `COLUMNS` respectively. And on creation of a table unless you defined a comment it would have not inserted into the respective comments table. And when you query on `TABLE_COMMENTS` or `COLUMN_COMMENTS` table, it would have fetched `Empty set...` satisfying your where condition.

Comment: Sir I have used above answer query and gives me a single row but when I am using query to fetch column name then it give me column name 3 times, see above answers query and comment, I have mentioned it. will you help me for that ?

Comment: @user3117841 You, however, definitely need to use `table_schema` in where clause, otherwise duplicate table names from other databases too will be fetched.

Comment: Yes I have used that one also, see above answers comments then it avoids duplicates.